Could an alien pathogen actually have an effect on us?
A very common trope (and one I plan to implement) is the alien parasite/virus/bacteria/fungus that arrives on an asteroid/is encountered by astronaut explorers/is brought to us by aliens unwittingly and then causes problems. I write mostly-hard sci-fi and the issue I encounter is that it seems astronomically unlikely that an alien pathogen of any variety (parasitic worm, virus, bacterium, fungus, microorganism, bioweapon) would actually "work" on an Earth species (or vice versa - Earth pathogens wouldn't "work" on alien life).
My specific case is that of pathogens originating on Earth vs. those originating on planet Prima, which is populated with predominantly-silicon-based life (low temperatures, slower metabolisms, biochemistries based on methane, nitrates, and silanes). Prima is also home to a silicon-based civilization that eventually, through their FTL-powered galactic exploration, eventually reaches Earth and discovers humanity. They breathe nitrogen at around Earth pressure and are comfortable in temperatures about 230 degrees Fahrenheit colder than humans and at about 1/10th Earth gravity; they can thus comfortably breathe and live on Titan, although it's not a perfect match it's not lethal for them to step outside of their lander ships. Like Earth, Prima also hosts a very wide variety of microorganisms including pathogens that are extremely deadly to primans.
What I want to have happen (and what many other authors want to have happen) is for these diseases, usually viruses, to also be deadly to humans. Alternatively, it could be the basic gut/skin bacteria of the primans that are lethal to humans, or it could be our passive bacteria that kill primans at great speed, or one of their passive bacteria unlocks our brain's full capacity, or it could be that our deadliest diseases act as cures/medicine/drugs for them. Whatever the case, the point is that one world's pathogens are biologically-compatible with the host species of the other world.
The issue is that I don't see how that's even remotely feasible. Not only has the alien pathogen never encountered a human cell or anything like it (and neither has the Earth pathogen encountered a priman cell or anything like it), but the two species operate on entirely-different biochemistries and function in completely-different ways. What I want to have happen is for some pathogen of Prima to be able to have some sort of effect on humans - if I can figure out how to get an alien virus to kill a human, I'll be happy. I would have simply said "this virus kills humans", but life on Prima never evolved anything biochemically-similar to DNA and I would imagine that the Primavirus would be virtually inert in humans.
So, is there a type of pathogen that could feasibly infect/attack/have some sort of effect on a species with a completely different biochemistry?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Of course this isn't opinion-based, what are the close voters even thinking???

Don't forget those edits, @controlgroup! I'd like to get this reopened.

I could believe that cross-biology pathogens might actually be directly poisonous rather than infectious per se. That might not be the case with something from an alien biology.
Plenty of Earth microbes produce toxins but are not, so far as I know, actually themselves toxic.
Plus, of course, lots of silica-based stuff is not exactly healthy to breath, lots of sharp edges.
As for cross-biology parasites finding a home in species of the other biology, that seems unlikely to say the least.

I've got no trouble seeing an alien fungus or bacterium using a human as a growth substrate.  Earth life can grow on (and slowly break down) rocks, after all.

A parasite doesn't have to find a home to be deadly. If a parasite enters the human body looking for a home but can't find one, both its entry and exit could cause some pretty serious damage - perhaps even more, since a parasite that does find a home would settle down rather than continuing to move around the body. (Citation: a SciShow video I've forgotten the name of.)

Just because a microorganism is toxic doesn't mean that enough of it could get into the other biome's inhabitants to cause toxicity.  Toxins that affect living things in very small quantities tend to be either evolved to be toxic, or radioactive.

The effect doesn't have to be biological
Suppose I punch you in the face, or drop a brick on you from a height. Obviously, we're both biological. Is the punch or the falling brick a biological effect, then? Or suppose a lion bites your throat out - is that a biological effect?
Clearly it isn't. And the same applies for your alien biology. They can very easily do things which cause basic physical damage to your body - perhaps on the outside, perhaps internally from inhaling or ingestion - which don't need any biological compatibility between species.
There are so many mechanisms for this, it's almost impossible to count. Anything related to silicosis would be obvious, but there are many other possibilities.

You're probably out of luck.  With that great a difference in the environments of the two worlds and their species, any microorganism that lives on species of one of your two worlds would be right out of its comfort zone on organisms of the other world.  Since Primans don't have DNA, their viruses and ours would be just so much inert junk to those from the other world.  If the chirality of biologically-produced amino acids and sugars is the same on both worlds, you have a chance, otherwise, forget it.
If the chirality of biological molecules is the same, then the only organisms likely to affect members of the other biome would be extremophiles... on the relatively cold Priman side, extremophiles in very hot environments, and on the relatively hot terrestrial side, extremophiles in very cold environments.  But these organisms wouldn't be pathogens of the sentient species of their world, they'd be things that those species might run across when looking for a place on the other world where they might be comfortable without a lot of protective gear.
If the chirality of either amino acids or sugars are different between worlds, again, you're out of luck, even with extremophiles.  While DNA may not be a common genetic structure, amino acids and sugars are probably going to be common, given that they can be synthesised without biological intervention on many worlds by natural processes.
About the only form of cross-species infection you might have is viral concepts that are as prone to causing certain aberrant thought patterns in the other sentient species as that in which it originated.  An example of one of these viral concepts that might find primans just as susceptible as humans is Scientology.  I could name others, but their adherents are more common in our society, and those adherents are likely to take offense that I could point out that I believe their beliefs to be delusions.

I was thinking primarily about genes, not memes (in the memetic sense) - that's some creativity right there. +1

@controlgroup Viral memes can be just as infectious as any pathogen, and can cause delusions, altered personality traits, and violent behavior.  As they include an imperative to spread the meme to other people, that is what makes them viral.  They've been lurking around human society for thousands of years... Scientology is just one of the most recent.  It's just a matter of thinking about human beliefs in a particular way...

It actually fits with the story too which is perfect. This is a very good answer in my opinion, if only by the relevant examples.

Easy.
Aliens arrived to Earth. It means they are very technologically advanced. Their machinery uses carbon based polimers and fluids, e.g. lubricants.
The aliens visited thousands if not millions of worlds before finding humanity. Statistically speaking they had to find life. The only two life forms in existence being these aliens and humans makes no sense.
A good chunk of life they find would be carbon based. Some virus-like pathogen survived in alien machinery and attacked humans.
No one expected it for the reasons you mentioned.

Silicon-based, you say?
How about some of their microorganisms being dangerous not for humans and other life forms directly, but to our infrastructure and chemical environment instead?
Imagine things that, when subject to sunlight, erode concrete?
Deplete the soil of nitrates? Or the other way round, have nitrates as their byproduct?
Given time, they could deplete a lot of things our biosphere is used to, like nitrogen in the air.
They could also form unexpected symbiotic relationships with our microorganisms that deal with silicon, e.g. diatoms - and thus create a kind of inedible diatoms that will alter the aquatic food chains dramatically.

I don’t think that silanes would be very effective on Earth as they tend to decompose in contact with oxygen. Silane itself is flammable and the flammability risk increases with the length of the silicon chain. The presence of even mild oxidizing agents such as nitrates would make things unstable even on the home planet. So some chemical adjustment might be a good idea.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_silicon-hydrogen_compounds
That said there is still scope for alien bacteria to cause problems. The scope within chemistry is vast beyond all reckoning and all we have to go on is the “tiny” slice of chemistry we see on Earth plus a piffling few million chemicals man has made so far (the chemistry of life on Earth is also vast beyond reckoning, its just that the totality of chemical possibilities is “vaster” by more orders of magnitude than you can shake a stick at).
So if you were to allow organic chemistry on your planet, which has the lions share of chemical options then the world is your oyster.
Perhaps alien bacteria don’t share our DNA, protein or sugars, but consume particular substances which are found in their native environment and are also found on Earth, say hydrocarbons in a wide variety of forms. If the alien bacteria can survive in our relatively high temperature world they could find a range of homes on Earth. If such bacteria were breathed in and entered the human body these bacteria might feast on the long chain fatty acids that make up our cell membranes. Although fatty acids are not not strictly hydrocarbons, they do contain long hydrocarbon tails and it is not beyond possibility that an adaptable bacteria could chew up the hydrocarbon tail and spit out the acid head chewed down to an acetic or even formic acid residue.
Our immune system would have a great deal of difficulty in tackling an intruder that did not use proteins so would have no protein coat to bind to and engulfing anything that ate cell membranes and generated formic acid would not end well.

Yeah, you're not going to get any silicon-based micro-organisms infecting Earth life, but carbon-based alien micro-organisms might be able to get somewhere.

@nick012000 I think you've overlooked the possibilities here. Don't think of the silicon-based lifeforms infecting humanity. Think of them as parasites whose waste products are toxic to humans. Human immune systems wouldn't treat a silicon life form any differently than it would any grain of sand... but if that living grain of sand pooped out something really nasty and ate something useful for good measure... Buahahahahaha!

@JBH Silicon-based life wouldn't be able to survive on Earth any better than we'd be able to survive on the surface of Venus. Depending on how their biochemistry worked, silicon lifeforms would either exist at extremely cold or extremely hot temperatures.

@nick012000 Maybe. But it's an assumption because we don't have an example of anything but carbon-based terrestrial-based life. The universe is constantly surprising us! I'm not a fan of WB.SE being "physics-lite." I think there's more than enough space to use what Slarty has said to rationalize exactly what the OP wants - and I think it's perfectly believable because there's no more evidence to say a silicon-based lifeform can't survive on Earth than there to say it can.

@JBH I would not want to press this too hard, because as you suggest we lack evidence. That said my point about silanes being flammable in an oxygen atmosphere does not bode well for a silane based virus in our atmosphere. Maybe there are other silicon base possibilities, but I have my doubts, silicon does not appear to have the chemical scope of carbon.

Viruses work by injecting their own viral RNA into the hosts's DNA, thereby "modifying" the host cell into producing more viruses. After it's done pumping out more viruses, the cell dies. It's highly unlikely that any extraterrestrial life has a compatible method of storing genetic information, so unless the material itself is poisonous, it would most likely do nothing.

Lots of Things Kill:
The one GOOD thing about biology for your purposes is that biology is fragile.

The alien pathogens may kill humans for completely different reasons than they kill aliens. At the very slow metabolic rate of these beings, radioactive decay might be a very real factor in metabolic processes. The diseases could emit alpha or beta particles after getting into humans.

The diseases probably die at our temps, but accelerated enzymatic activity may mean a reaction that occurs VERY slowly in them causes an abrupt reaction via a molecule that could be extremely resistant to degradation.

The components of the disease may be extremely carcinogenic to humans, or simply highly toxic.

The pathogens could provoke an extremely violent immune/allergic response from humans (even if not causing a disease) where the "infection" site becomes swollen, the humans spike a fever, etc. acutely.

The pathogen may trigger a specific auto-immune reaction so their own antibodies start attacking skin, joints, intestinal linings, and so on that continue long after the original exposure.


So fear not, it may not be the ALIEN biology that is killing you. It could simply kill you because it can.

If there are aliens, there will be many aliens. Some of them will be similar to us. Your aliens probably had contact with aliens similar to use.
Depending on the technological advancement, there might not be any infectious diseases…
Or there might be new forms of disease like rogue nanobots. Those might be able to infect anything no matter how different the biology is.

Zoonotic Bacteria/Fungi
In its home ecology, the pathogen is beneficial; it eats something that either has no effect on the host species or would actively harm it. It just so happens that due to the different biochemistries, whatever this "something" is, it is necessary in terrestrial lifeforms. The pathogen, benevolent in its host species, is very much not benevolent in humans. Note that this is the simplest of laymen's terms; as is sci-fi tradition, you will probably want to dress this up with all sorts of technobabble.
Another benefit of using a bacteria, fungus, or assorted alien analogues  is that the pathogen only needs a sufficient supply of nutrients to reproduce. Unlike viruses, it is not dependent on some (relatively) hyper-specific quirk of the host's biochemistry.
If you are looking for more information, I suggest reading The Andromeda Strain; while the precise details differ, it is a good example of when and where to apply handwavium, lampshading, and so on in these sorts of scenarios.

The temperature difference would make this very unlikely.

@MontyWild Whoops, didn't see the "Science-Based" tag. In my defense, I wrote this directly before bed after a very long day.
